# Is there a standard command that always exits with a signal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, exit-status

This question is very similar to [Is there a standard command that always exits with a failure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43199/is-there-a-standard-command-that-always-exits-with-a-failure)

I'm writing some code which I need to test that it handles subprocesses gracefully when the child process exits due to a signal (say `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`).

Is there something concise that I can call like `true` or `false` to achieve this with signals?

Comment: Just send a signal with `kill` to `$$`.  `$$` contains the PID of the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok :-)

The script you want looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

kill $$
```

This relies on the fact that `kill` is a builtin command, and *not* the `/bin/kill` program.

Comment: Thanks so much! For future Python folks doing something similar: `Popen(["bash", "-c", "kill -SIGTERM $$"])` for my unit test!

Comment: What difference would it make if `kill` was an external program?

Comment: Could you say something more about that last statement of yours about `kill` needing to be built-in?

Comment: It might be more useful for testing if it took two args: (a) A time to sleep -- children that instantly die may not be a fair test. (b) A signal to send itself -- your control code might want to report the child's reason for failure.

Comment: @user414777 you're right, it doesn't matter. It would work with /bin/kill as well.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant okay, make the last line `sleep ${1:-1} ; kill -n ${2:-15} $$`